# Calculating data from table

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a random table with students who are doing assignments. I want to calculate the average grade of each student when I press the button. Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

```js
function calculate() {
  var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('shauna1').value);
  var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('shauna2').value);
  var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('shauna3').value);
  var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('shauna4').value);
  var grade5 = parseFloat(document.getElementbyId('shauna5').value);
  var average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3 + grade4 + grade5) / 5;
  document.getElementById("shaunafinal").innerHTML = average;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Student ID </th>
    <th>Student Name </th>
    <th>Assignment 1 </th>
    <th>Assignment 2 </th>
    <th>Assignment 3 </th>
    <th>Assignment 4 </th>
    <th>Assignment 5 </th>
    <th>Final Grade </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!-- contenteditable="true" means you can edit it.
          id = "left" lets you edit part of the table differently than the rest -->
    <td id="left">16710169 </td>
    <td id="left">Shauna Goodman </td>
    <td id="shauna1" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td id="shauna2" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td id="shauna3" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td id="shauna4" contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td id="shauna5" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td id="shaunafinal"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710170 </td>
    <td id="left">Paul Smith </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">55 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">45 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">80 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710171 </td>
    <td id="left">Marie Mckenna </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">66 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710172 </td>
    <td id="left">Saoirse McGuire </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">45 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">85 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">95 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">81 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">59 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710173 </td>
    <td id="left">Nathaniel Kingston </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">46 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">30 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">28 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710174 </td>
    <td id="left">Adam Jones </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">96 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">78 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">63 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710175 </td>
    <td id="left">Melanie Song </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">96 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">95 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">98 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">97 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710176 </td>
    <td id="left">Sarah Cesal </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">38 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710177 </td>
    <td id="left">Teresa Purcell </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">10 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">38 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="left">16710178 </td>
    <td id="left">James Hennessey </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">80 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
    <td contenteditable="true">98 </td>
    <td>- </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">
          Submit
         </button>
```

The javascript part should only work for the first student, but I want that part to work before I go on with the others.

Comment: HTML id's should be unique for the whole document, if you want to use the same id with multiple elements use a CSS `class` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById('shauna1').innerText;
```

you wrote "getElementById" incorrectly... plus - id's should be unique value per element. otherwise, use class instead.

Comment: `function calculate()
{
 var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna1').innerText);
  var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna2').innerText);
  var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna3').innerText);
  var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna4').innerText);
  var grade5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna5').innerText);
  var average = (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5;
 document.getElementById("shaunafinal").innerHTML = average;

}`
This does not work either if this is what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues in JavaScript code:

1. Typo in `getElementbyId`. It should be [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText).
2. You can't get a value of a `td` with a `.value`. You should use [.innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) instead.

The correct code should look like:

```
function calculate() {
    var grade1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna1').innerText);
    var grade2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna2').innerText);
    var grade3 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna3').innerText);
    var grade4 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna4').innerText);
    var grade5 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('shauna5').innerText);
    var average = (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5;
    document.getElementById("shaunafinal").innerHTML = average;
}
```

Also here you can find a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5wtbjr7/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
function calculate() {
  // get table element
  let table = document.querySelector('table');
  // get all rows
  let rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  // remove thead and loop over rows
  Object.keys(rows).forEach(key => {
    let row = rows[key];
    // get data elements
    let datasets = row.querySelectorAll('.d');
    let total = 0;
    // loop over datasets
    datasets.forEach(dataset => {
      // add up all values
      total += parseInt(dataset.innerHTML);
    });
    // calc the avg
    let avg = total / datasets.length;
    try {
        // handle dom mm exeption for thead
        let el = row.getElementsByClassName('davg')[0].innerHTML = avg;
    } catch (e) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Student ID </th>
    <th>Student Name </th>
    <th>Assignment 1 </th>
    <th>Assignment 2 </th>
    <th>Assignment 3 </th>
    <th>Assignment 4 </th>
    <th>Assignment 5 </th>
    <th>Final Grade </th>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
  <!-- contenteditable="true" means you can edit it.
  id = "left" lets you edit part of the table differently than the rest -->
    <td id = "left">16710169 </td>
    <td id = "left">Shauna Goodman </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg">-</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710170 </td>
    <td id = "left">Paul Smith </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">30 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710171 </td>
    <td id = "left">Marie Mckenna </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">74 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">61 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">97 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">118 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710172 </td>
    <td id = "left">Saoirse McGuire </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">30 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710173 </td>
    <td id = "left">Nathaniel Kingston </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">170 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710174 </td>
    <td id = "left">Adam Jones </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">10 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">118 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710175 </td>
    <td id = "left">Melanie Song </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">10 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710176 </td>
    <td id = "left">Sarah Cesal </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">10 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">10 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710177 </td>
    <td id = "left">Teresa Purcell </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">22 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id = "left">16710178 </td>
    <td id = "left">James Hennessey </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">90 </td>
    <td class="d" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
    <td class="davg"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">
  Submit
</button>
```

Fully working example (just removed some data due to copy pasting)

Comment: Please write some comments about what you have changed.

Comment: @alistaircol basicly I just rewrote the entire js part and added classes in the HTML talbe

Comment: Thanks a million for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it worked:

```
  function calculate() {
var grade1 = Number(document.getElementById('shauna1').innerHTML);
var grade2 = Number(document.getElementById('shauna2').innerHTML);
var grade3 = Number(document.getElementById('shauna3').innerHTML);
var grade4 = Number(document.getElementById('shauna4').innerHTML);
var grade5 = Number(document.getElementById('shauna5').innerHTML);
var average = (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5;
document.getElementById("shaunafinal").innerHTML = average;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Include `<thead>` and `<tbody>` into the table

```
<table id="table">
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Access table with

```
var table = document.getElementById("table");
```

Access `<th>`s in `<thead>` and `<tr>`s in `<tbody>` with

```
var ths = table.querySelectorAll("thead th");
var trs = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr");
```

The **outer** loop has the length of the `<tbody>` `<tr>`s and the **inner** loop has the length of the `<thead>` `<th>`s.

#### In total

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table"),
  ths_l = table.querySelectorAll("thead th").length,
  trs = table.querySelectorAll("tbody tr"),
  trs_l = trs.length,
  s = 2;

function calculate() {
  for (var i = 0; i < trs_l; i += 1) {
    var res = 0,
      c = 0;
    for (var j = s; j < (ths_l - 1); j += 1) { // Starts with 2
      var textContent = trs[i].children[j].textContent,
        n = textContent.replace(/\D/g, ""); // Delete everything that is not a digit
      if (textContent.match("-")) {
        c += 1;
      }
      res += +n; // String to number, +"" === 0
    }
    trs[i].children[ths_l - 1].textContent = res / (ths_l - 1 - s - c); // Calculate average and insert into <td>
  }
}
```

```html
<table id="table" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Student ID </th>
      <th>Student Name </th>
      <th>Assignment 1 </th>
      <th>Assignment 2 </th>
      <th>Assignment 3 </th>
      <th>Assignment 4 </th>
      <th>Assignment 5 </th>
      <th>Final Grade </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!-- contenteditable="true" means you can edit it.
      id = "left" lets you edit part of the table differently than the rest -->
      <td id="left">16710169 </td>
      <td id="left">Shauna Goodman </td>
      <td id="shauna1" contenteditable="true">70 </td>
      <td id="shauna2" contenteditable="true">60 </td>
      <td id="shauna3" contenteditable="true">40 </td>
      <td id="shauna4" contenteditable="true">90 </td>
      <td id="shauna5" contenteditable="true">88 </td>
      <td id="shaunafinal"> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710170 </td>
      <td id="left">Paul Smith </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">55 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">45 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">80 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710171 </td>
      <td id="left">Marie Mckenna </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">66 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710172 </td>
      <td id="left">Saoirse McGuire </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">45 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">85 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">95 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">81 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">59 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710173 </td>
      <td id="left">Nathaniel Kingston </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">46 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">30 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">28 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710174 </td>
      <td id="left">Adam Jones </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">96 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">78 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">63 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710175 </td>
      <td id="left">Melanie Song </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">96 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">90 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">95 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">98 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">97 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710176 </td>
      <td id="left">Sarah Cesal </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">- </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">38 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710177 </td>
      <td id="left">Teresa Purcell </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">70 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">10 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">38 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="left">16710178 </td>
      <td id="left">James Hennessey </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">80 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">50 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">40 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">25 </td>
      <td contenteditable="true">98 </td>
      <td>- </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">
      Submit
     </button>
```